# Why is arc4random returning negative numbers sometimes?

Tags: objective-c, gnustep, arc4random

I'm using `arc4random()` to generate numbers in a certain range. However, I will intermittently receive negative numbers. I'm not doing anything strange:

```
if([aBug x] == -1) {
    x = arc4random() % columns;
}

if([aBug y] == -1) {
    y = arc4random() % rows;
}
```

Here, `x` and `y` sometimes get set to negative values. `x` and `y` are both of type `int`.

Comment: Probably not critical here, but in general it's recommend to use `arc4random_uniform(columns)` instead. From the docs: arc4random_uniform() is recommended over constructions like `arc4random() % upper_bound` as it avoids "modulo bias" when the upper bound is not a power of two.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you want to declare x and y to be of type `u_int32_t` instead of `int`. I.e., you should be using unsigned variables instead of signed.

Or, use a signed integer that's larger than 32 bits (e.g., `uint64_t`/`long long`).

Comment: I basically ended up using `NSUInteger`, which seems to work. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 4):

Since `arc4random()` is always positive:

> The arc4random() function returns pseudo-random numbers in the range of 0 to (2**32)-1

[<sup><sup><sup>[Source]</sup></sup></sup>](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man3/arc4random.3.html)

I would have to deduce that `columns` or `rows` is "arbitrarily" negative. Moding a positive number by a negative number will return a negative number.

What are the data types for rows and columns?

Comment: Sorry just saw this. Looks like SO didn't give me a notification regarding answers to this question! Both `columns` and `rows` are of type `int` and are positive.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem. I have no idea why this fixed it but changing from

```
(int)arc4Random()%4
```

to

```
(int)(arc4Random()%4)
```

seemed to work for me.